# Modelling a system using a hierarchy of interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance, interface

I am trying to model the capacity utilisation of several heterogenous storage systems in code.

All of the storage systems have some simple concepts that I am trying to abstract away from their specific implementation. For example, all the systems use disks for storage. Disks can be collected into a group, and space allocated to volumes from these groups. Some systems have specific implementation details that mean they behave differently to the other systems. For example, several of the systems have different classes of disk (e.g. fast, slow) and the groups of disks belong to a class. Some of the systems simply have groups of disks without an associated disk class.

I have spent some time trying to abstract away as much of the detail as I can, and have written a handful of interfaces to represent these abstractions. For example, `IStorageContainer` has a Name, Description, some flags to show whether various storage technologies are supported by the container, and a raw total size. My desire is that `IStorageContainer` could represent a single disk, a group of disks, a disk class, or a volume. Critically, `IStorageContainer` has a parent `IStorageContainer` and some child `IStorageContainer`s to represent how groups of disks are divided into volumes, and a volume has to belong to a group of disks.

I have built classes to represent each of the storage systems, each implementing `IStorageContainer`. I can create a `List<IStorageContainer>`, add a mix of objects - of different derived types but all which implement `IStorageContainer` - and then iterate over the list to find, for example, those objects which are of a specific type. If I know in advance the derived types of the objects in my list, I can cast them back to their original type from `IStorageContainer`:

```
        foreach (var container in allContainers.SelectMany(
            container => container.Children.Where(
                child => child is System1Volume))
        .Cast<System1Volume>())
        {
            // Do stuff with System1Volume
            Console.WriteLine($"{container.Name}");
        }
```

However, if I have a `List<IStorageContainer>` and I don't know the contents in advance (i.e. they're "discovered" at run-time), and I want to show different UI for each of the types of `IStorageContainer` in the list, I have no idea how to discover the underlying types. Doing this with a huge series of "if" statements seems messy.

```
        foreach
            (var container in allContainers.SelectMany
                (
                    container => container.Children
                )
            )
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{container.Name} is a {container.GetType()}");
            if (container.GetType() == typeof(System1Volume))
            {
                // Show the System1DiskGroup UI
                var typedContainer = (System1Volume)container;
                Console.WriteLine(typedContainer.WordThatOnlySystem1VolumesKnow);
            }
            else if (container.GetType()==typeof(System2Volume))
            {
                // Show the System2DiskGroup UI
                var typedContainer = (System2Volume)container;
                Console.WriteLine(typedContainer.WordThatOnlySystem2VolumesKnow);
            }
        }
```

Is there a better way?

Finally, suppose `System1Volume` only supports a set of specific derived types in the `Children` list. Can I use an interface, derived from `IStorageContainer` as a constraint to support this?

Comment: If I understood what the issue is, `factory pattern` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @12seconds are you proposing to use the factory pattern to generate the necessary UI components based on the derived type of the `IStorageContainer`?

Comment: Consider giving `IStorageContainer` less to do. Specifically, it makes sense for disks to contain volumes, and further grouping disks into arrays, but this is a strict hierarchy array -> disks -> volumes, and can be modelled as such. Having an interface that allows volumes to contain disk groups, or disks to contain other disks (unless prevented at runtime through type checks) seems suboptimal. Even if more flexibility is needed, parallel hierarchies are usually easier than stuffing it all into one super-generic interface.